# Swing JPanel switching out of scope

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I'm new to Swing and my experience with Java is also limited. I'm creating a GUI but in order to get to the main screen, a login is required first. I've structured my classes like this:

Root of the class tree:

```
public class master {

static mainwindow mainWindow;
static login loginScreen;

static JFrame frame;}
```

The result of a correct username and password should switch the panel from loginscreen to mainwindow. My problem is that when in the class "login" the login action is handled, I can't access my mainWindow Panel or the frame, because they are in a class thats 'higher'.

I hope what I'm asking is clear, if not I will edit my post with more code and elaboration.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using static variables or methods in the way you are doing, to give methods and variables a global scope, since in doing so you lose many of the advantages of object oriented programming.

You should have a main class, perhaps you can call it a control class that runs everything and that passes references to where it's needed. Usually my login windows are modal dialogs, such as a JDialog, that are modal to the main window which is a JFrame.

For instance, something like...

```
public class MasterControl {
   private MainView mainView = new MainView(this);
   private LoginView loginView = new LoginView(this);

   public MasterControl() {
      loginAndStart();
   }

   private void loginAndStart() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MasterControl");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainView.getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      JDialog loginDialog = new JDialog(frame, "Log In", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
      loginDialog.getContentPane().add(loginView.getMainPanel());
      loginDialog.pack();
      loginDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
      loginDialog.setVisible(true);

      // here extract info from loginView, ask model to validate login credentials
      // and then change main view.
   }
```

Comment: You've never had a need for static data? Ever? Granted, the OP's use of static is likely wrong, but I'm commenting on your empahasis on your "Nothing... period" comment.

Comment: @splungebob: I am 99.9% sure that the OP should not be using static in the way that he is doing, that he is likely using it in order to allow ability to get references to objects on a "global" scope, which is not a good reason for its use. But you are right of course that I was a *bit* over-zealous in my pronouncement and that I probably should re-phrase that. If you're going to use static anything, you'd better justify the need.

Comment: LOL - I was going to say 99.99%, but why split hairs?

Answer (score 3):

One of the important concepts in OO is separation of responsibility.

In your case, it is NOT the responsibility of the `Login` component to decide what action should be taken after a successful login (you could also argue unsuccessful as well).

In this case, you need some way for the login component to inform interested parties of the state of the login process.  This is best achieved using something like the observer pattern.

Basically, this means, that you have some kind of listener/callback that can react to changes.

In the following example, I've used a `CardLayout` as my main means of switching the views, but you could, just as easily, use a `JDialog` for the login form (as Hovercraft has done) and load the main frame once the login has been processed successfully.

[image]

```
public class TestCardLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCardLogin();
    }

    public TestCardLogin() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements LoginListener {

        private MainPane mainPane;
        private LoginPane loginPane;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new CardLayout());

            mainPane = new MainPane();
            loginPane = new LoginPane(this);

            add(mainPane, "MAIN");
            add(loginPane, "LOGIN");

            ((CardLayout) getLayout()).show(this, "LOGIN");

        }

        @Override
        public void loginSuccessful() {
            ((CardLayout) getLayout()).show(this, "MAIN");
        }

        @Override
        public void loginFailed() {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Login failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        public MainPane() {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome!");
            Font font = label.getFont();
            label.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(label);
        }
    }

    public class LoginPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField user;
        private JPasswordField password;
        private JButton login;
        private LoginListener loginListener;

        public LoginPane(LoginListener listener) {
            this.loginListener = listener;
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel("User name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            user = new JTextField(12);
            password = new JPasswordField(12);

            add(user, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(password, gbc);

            login = new JButton("Login");

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(login, gbc);

            login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    boolean accept = (boolean) (((int) Math.round(Math.random() * 1)) == 0 ? true : false);
                    if (accept) {
                        loginListener.loginSuccessful();
                    } else {
                        loginListener.loginFailed();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public interface LoginListener {

        public void loginSuccessful();

        public void loginFailed();
    }
}
```